# Calling extern C function called with void*

Tags: d, ffi

I have a C library which takes opaque pointers in the header.

Here's my C header

```
typedef void* dbaxRange_p;
typedef void* dbaxFunction_p;

extern "C" {
    // ... lots of other methods...
    EXPORT dbaxRange_p range_d(const double value);
    EXPORT void add_param(dbaxFunction_p func, dbaxRange_p arg);
    EXPORT dbaxFunction_p dbax_function(const char* name, const int num_params);
    // Call method taking void*
    EXPORT dbaxRange_p call(dbaxFunction_p func);
}
```

Here's my D interface
CDbax.d:

```
extern (C):
alias void *dbaxFunction_p;
alias void *dbaxRange_p;

extern (C) {
dbaxRange_p  range_d(double value);
void  add_param(dbaxFunction_p func, dbaxRange_p arg);
dbaxFunction_p  dbax_function(const char *name, int num_params);
dbaxRange_p  call(dbaxFunction_p func);
}
```

And here's my call to the function

```
class Dbax {
     // ...
    dbaxFunction_p func_;
    this(string name) {
       func_ = dbax_function(std.string.toStringz(name),0);
    }
    Dbax add(double val) {
        auto rng = range_d(val);
        add_param(func_,rng);
        return this;
    }
    dbaxRange_p call() {
        return call(cast(dbaxFunction_p) this.func_);
    }
}
```

main.d

```
import CDbax;
void test()
{
    auto res = new CDbax.Dbax("GetVersionNumber").add(0.24).call();
}
```

But I get this error:-

```
CDbax.d(113): Error: function CDbax.Dbax.call () is not callable using argument types (void*)
```

**Update**
Answer is that there's a namespace clash. It picked up my C FFI call rather than the Dbax class call() function. I'll ask a  follow up SO question as to why

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is simply a case of it trying to call the method `call` instead of the global function. (BTW are you sure the C function is called `call` and that isn't a macro? It is kinda rare for a C function to have such a naked name.)

Anyway, when you're inside a class, it always looks to the class first for members and D does *not* overload across units unless you specifically ask it to by `alias innerName = full.outer.name;` The explanation for why is here: http://dlang.org/hijack.html basically it is so adding a global function later doesn't break the class by introducing a new, confusing overload. The class' author should be able to focus on just the class' source without worrying about a new global written by another programmer in a module far, far away making her code more confusing.

The easiest way to solve this in your case is to use a full name, or at least the global scope operator in your call:

```
    return call(cast(dbaxFunction_p) this.func_); // before

    return .call(cast(dbaxFunction_p) this.func_); // after
```

The leading dot means "look it up in the top-level namespace". (BTW, similarly, you can explicitly use `this.call` when you want it to look only at `this`.)

When these things come up, you can also prepend the module name to disambiguate if you prefer to be even more explicit:

```
  foo.bar.call(); // looks in foo.bar
```